# Using a development board to charge a lipo battery

Tags: batteries, charge, development

Ok, I'm not specialist in electronic but just enthousiast.
I'm searching a solution to charge lipo battery in-board (to build tablet with a micro computer like Raspberry Pi)

So, I have seen this development board, because I need a lot of power (5V 4A during 5~6 hours)

[The board is a microship MCP1630V](http://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails.aspx?PartNO=mcp1630rd-ddbk3)

I have understood that the battery must be plug at the same place as the input power, but how about the balance circuit ?

For example this [battery](http://www.hobbygaga.com/fr-lion-power-14-8v-10400mah-25c-batterie-lipo-p266907.htm) (14.8v, 10400mAh), is it possible to charge it with this board?

Sorry by advance for my bad english, and my non knowledge about the subject, so be indulgent!

However, any help for my project is welcome!

Answer (score 2):

The battery is connected to a different connector, not the same place as the input power. There is no pack balancing, it seems. It looks likely to work, and charge safely, but it won't balance the cells and this may affect pack lifetime.

The output from battery power through the buck converter is 6V rather than 5V. This is not ideal. You might be able to change this by altering the sense resistors on the board.

(4A seems rather high power consumption for a "tablet"?)

Comment: Oh yes, I have wrote a mistake. I would like to say that the input power of the system (the pi & all) is pluged at the same place that the general input, not the battery. Sorry for that). And I think about 4A, because the screen is a laptop screen, big (17'1). The inverter needs 12V to work, and the controler board need 5V 4A.

Comment: And yes, I thougth use a step-down to have 5V input for the pi. So, do you think it will charge if the balance conector is not plugged? Thanks for your help !